# Is there a way to cache includes in xslt?

Tags: xslt, caching

When transforming on client side, the browser gets all the includes everytime the transformation is applied. I find it makes the application run slower.

Is there a way, with XSLT, to cache the includes so it does not download each file everytime is used again?

I am using a service worker now but I was wondering if there is another way.

Comment: So how do you initiate the transformation client-side, with e.g. `<?xml-stylesheet?>` in an XML document you load? Or with JavaScript? Which software is "the browser"? I don't see why caching in the browser would work for e.g. the XML document and the main stylesheet but not for included ones. But I haven't run any tests now.

Comment: The **browser** being Chrome, Edge... When you run the xml the first time, the page is rendered and that is fine but,  if you want to use javascript to apply another transformation by passing parameters or what not,  it seems to get the main xslt template from cache or disk but not the includes.

Comment: I have a vague recollection that the Chrome issue a long standing, known problem. Edge being now based on Chromium might have inherited it. It might be worth to search the Chrome/Chromium bug issues database for known bug reports.

Answer (score 0):

I would have expected the included files to be cached the way everything else is. However, even if it's cached, there's still a signficant cost in that you're compiling the stylesheet every time it's used. The way to avoid that is to redesign your site as a "single page application", so following a link loads new content and transforms it using the existing already-loaded stylesheet.

SaxonJS [disclaimer: my company's product] is designed very much on the basis that you will compile the stylesheet once and then use it repeatedly. You can even precompile the stylesheet on the server.

Comment: I'm having this issue because I've designed my application as an SPA and even if I divide it in modules, I would use common components like say modals that can be used across all the application. The idea is then include this components so they can be reused. It works as a charm and saves me so much time but I was wondering if there was any workaround regarding the cache